# C# Selenium Google Sheet

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, google-sheets

I have code:

```
driver.Navigate().GotoUlr("https://www.youtube.com/")
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("abcd").Click();
```

I want to import many links to dont have change code every time I run, like:

in google sheet:

```
colum 1:
youtube.com
google.com
bing.com
....about 100 lines

colum 2:
abcd
zxcv
mkopdsh
yuiofhxd
....about 100 lines
```

[image: google sheet online Example]

How can I do that with C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be to import your excel file in the executable's directory.

Then you could open and parse it as xml with the HtmlAgilityPack package.
An other option would be to open and parse it as an excel file with EPPlus.